# Transform a vagrant box provisioned with puppet into an EC2 AMI and upload it to AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, puppet, vagrant

What is the best way to transform a vagrant box provisioned with puppet into an EC2 AMI and upload it to AWS?

Answer (score 1):

Transforming a Vagrant VM in to an AMI will be problematic. The easiest thing to do in this case is:

- Prepare your Puppet manifests and test locally with Vagrant
- Boot an EC2 instance, and use Puppet to configure that instance. You could use the cfn-init scripts, or manually run Puppet on the instance
- Create an AMI from this instance

The process is exactly the same as running Puppet on a local VM or physical hardware, except you will need to create an AMI once the instance is configured.